# Rails navigates back to error page after long running process

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is very likely to be the wrong way of doing it but I hope someone can point me in the correct direction

The problem is that `some_process` takes a while to execute if there is an error and if the browser goes to another page in the meanwhile, the page comes back to the edit page when it (`some_process`) does complete eventually.

(greatly simplified code)

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    result = some_process
    if result
      format.html { redirect_to :action => :index }
    else
      # error 
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end
end
```

How do you prevent this? `some_process` cannot be interrupted. Should it be run in another thread? Is there some method to prevent rendering the page if the user has lost interest and already gone elsewhere?
Should I check something before `render :edit` to see whether it is still on the same page?

Total Rails newbie question & I've exhausted my Google-fu.

Comment: What do you mean by user goes to other page. If the user navigates to other actions then request cycle is auto broken and therefore edit page will not render.

Comment: That's the problem, it isn't. The user goes to some other page on the site but when some_process completes, the page comes back to the page that is rendered by render :edit (which shows the error message) If the user leaves the site entirely, there is no problem, the request is terminated then.